# how to make a component diagram for my web service

Tags: rest, web-services, soa, component-diagram

So, for my school project i am making a system consisting of a reader application and a root-based dictionary web service. They will be linked through the REST API. I am following SOA as suggested by my supervisor. He told me to make component diagram for the dictionary web service.
Now, I am having difficulty to show the 'API Part' of the web service. How do I attach the API component with the rest of the service?

I made the following component diagram.
[image: component diagram]

any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.